# How can I load/save multiple files at once in c# wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, save

### Introduction

I am curretly working on a character sheet generator for my pen&paper group. Each character is stored in multiple xml files, which are saved and loaded using `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter`.

[image: Mutlipe Files]

### Problem

Currently I can only save to a single path, which is hardcoded to this path:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName) + "\\Saves\\Default"
```

I thought about using a `SaveFileDialog`, which would require me to pack all xml files into a single, large one, because it doesn't seem possible to save multiple files at once with this dialog, but I'd rather not do that, as of right now I often have to modify certain values and finding them is way more easy in small, structured files of a few hundred lines rather than one large file with a few thousand lines.

Altough saving into a single file seems to be common practice, if I take a look into the saves-folder of my videogames, I'd like to take a different approach, like this:

- All SavesFiles are in MyApplication/Saves/
- Each SaveFile is a folder
- The folder contains all character-data saved into multiple xml-files as seen above
- The Dialog for saving allows the user to either select an existing folder in MyApplication/Saves/ or create a new one.
- The dialog for loading shows all folders in MyApplication/Saves/

### Question

I have litterary no idea what kind of possiblities I have, so I'd like to know:

- **Are there any pre-existing windows-dialogs, that I can use for my idea?**
- **How would it be possible to create my own SaveFileDialog?**

Comment: Why not use the [`FolderBrowserDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog?view=netframework-4.8) to select the folder? The `SaveFileDialog` would be awkward to use as you would be selecting a name then ignoring it. Yes this is a "Windows Forms" dialog, but so is the `SaveFileDialog`...

Comment: @those who downvote/put it on hold. It would be helpful to communicate to me how you suggest to make this question more clear. I spent quite some effort to show what I have done so far and where my problem is, I also asked a Question as to "how to save/load multiple files in wpf at once?", because the SaveFileDialog won't let me properly do that, but having done nothing simular so far, it is quite hard to be more specific.

Comment: Google terms for more details. I think the whole folder browsing thing is a mistake.  You should use a folder or folders in localappdata. There's a framework special folders allows you to find where that is. Add a folder tree company / appname / version.  Then the users can't lose their data. Use serialisation / deserialisation of objects to save and read the data. Far better to work with objects in c# than xml. Serialisation is quite robust. For our game the only time i needed to change data was when i removed a couple of options off an enum. I used powershell to batch edit all my xml files.

Comment: I rewrote my question. Hope this makes it a little more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ron has suggested, you should look into using `FolderBrowseDialog`, which is in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace.

Say you have a `TextBox`, and two buttons named `BtnBrowse` which lets you browse file folder, and `BtnSave` which will save files.

Looks like this:

[image]

Then, in the `Browse` button, use it to let the user select folder path, and then save using the save button.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog = null;
    List<string> filesToSave = null;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        filesToSave = new List<string>
        {
            "A.txt",
            "B.txt",
            "C.txt"
        };
    }

    private void BtnBrowse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            TxtFolderPath.Text = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;
        }
    }

    private void BtnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var file in filesToSave)
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(TxtFolderPath.Text, file);
            File.WriteAllText(path, string.Format("Contents of {0}", file));
        }
    }
}
```